# How to change with regex multiple occurences between to points in multiple files

Tags: regex, notepad++

To make it simple: I have a lot of files in which a text 'chapter 1' and 'chapter 2' occurs.

I want to change every occurrence of 'blue' between 'chapter 1' and 'chapter 2' into 'green' with regex in notepad++. I tried something like:

Find: `(chapter 1)((.*?blue)*)(.*?chapter 2)`
Replace: `\1\2\3\4`

but event the Find reports: `Invalid regular expression`.

Comment: [Your regex is valid](https://regex101.com/r/UCQeoC/1).

Comment: I don't think that replacing all occurrences at once is possible. Try find `(chapter 1.*)(blue)(.*chapter 2)`, replace `\1green\3` and keep clicking on replace until no more matches are found.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^chapter 1\b|\G)(?:(?!\bblue\b)[\s\S])*\K\bblue\b(?=[\s\S]*chapter 2\b)`
- Replace with: `green`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                     # non capture group
    ^chapter 1\b            # literally
  |                       # OR
    \G                      # restart from last match position
)                       # end group
(?:                     # non capture group
    (?!\bblue\b)            # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't blue just after
    [\s\S]                  # any kind of characters
)*                      # end group, may appear 0 or more times
\K                      # forget all we have seen until this position
\bblue\b                # literally
(?=[\s\S]*chapter 2\b)  # positive lookahead, make sure we have "chapter 2" after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: @Thefourthbird: Thanks !  No, I didn't. But OP regex doesn't replace `blue` with `green`!

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, but it didn't work. I tried a lot of changes but even then.
If you have a better idea, please without worrying about blue as part of another word and so.

Comment: @evd: It works with your given example, I can't think of another answer without example. Please, edit your question and add test cases that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

@Toto:
The test with your example:
[image]

As you see, it is really not working at my place.
If you have a suggestion for a solution, maybe you can use less "\b". It is rather confusing for me {;-(}, being no so experienced and you don't have to bother for complete words and such. Thanks.

Comment: I don't get the problem, you haven't any `blue` in your text then, of course, the regex doesn't match.

Comment: You are right, of course. I choose the wrong screen shot.
After another 2 hours of analysis of your answer, I got it working in my application.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, there is still a problem. If there is a 'chapter 0' before 'chapter 1' and there is a 'blue' between 'chapter 0' and 'chapter 1' it is changed too.

Comment: Just replace begining of line `^` with `\A[\s\S]*`. If it works for you, I'll modify my answer tomorrow.